# Jquery in my custom zen theme

Tags: javascript

the following is my js file mymodule.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    alert('test');
});
```

and i just add this file in my customtheme.info .

scripts[] = js/mymodule.js

However, the js code only be executed at some pages, not all pages.

What could the problem will be?

Does anyone have the same situation before?

Please help me fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Drupal 7 to avoid conflicts with another library you should wrap your code in:

```
(function ($) {
  // Original JavaScript code.
})(jQuery);
```

To learn more visit: http://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#javascript_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Try it by implementing hook_init() into your .module file:

```
function YOURMODULE_init() {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'YOURMODULE')  ."/YOURSCRIPT.js",  array('every_page' => TRUE));
}
```

Also make sure your module is in its proper place: sites/all/modules/YOURMODULE  or a subfolder of this.